# function seems to malfunction when called concurrently

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading

I am facing a very weird problem (at least I think it is weird).

Basically I have a very simple function which is called from multiple threads concurrently. While calling the function from a single sequential thread seems to work correctly, when I call the function concurrently it seems to mess up data from different callers.

The actual code is hard to replicate standalone, I just wondered what the life/scope of python data structure is. If I call the same function multiple times concurrently their internal variables/arguments are independent from one another right?
I seem to remember I ran into a similar problem when I was using recursive functions, where a function's data whould persist from call to call, could this be the case?

Thanks

Comment: Function called concurrently should not get impacted by other threads if there are no global variables shared. See in the method description if its using any global variables.

Comment: Note: When you call the function concurrently, you do not get the response in the order the functions are called. I think you are expecting the response to be in same order in which functions are called

Comment: As far as I can see there are no global variables... @MoinuddinQuadri I don't mind about that, as long as each caller get's it's result I don't mind the order

Comment: Are you passing objects to the method from a common source?? Say i create object of A class Student and I create multiple threads and pass object inside the same method. Each time the roll no of student is added by 1. But since all threads are passing the same student object after the final call the student roll no will be incremented multiple times, and not just ones